# Non-static method requires a target in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to send a HTTP POST request in a controller.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult login([FromBody] ClubAPI.Models.AllRequest.login userid)
{
    using (DAL.ClubEntities db = new ClubEntities())
    {
        DAL.AspNetUser q = db.AspNetUsers.Single(t=>t.Id.Equals(userid.id.ToString()));

        if (q == null)
        {
            return Ok(new ClubAPI.Models.AllResponse.loginResponse
            {
                msg = "bad",
                state = false,
            });
        }
        return Ok(new ClubAPI.Models.AllResponse.loginResponse
        {
            msg = "good",
            state = true,
            token = q.UserName,
        });
    }
}
```

But now I get the error below:

> "Non-static method requires a target in webapi" i cant solve that. the
>   error is related to this line:
>   db.AspNetUsers.Single(t=>t.Id.Equals(userid.id.ToString()));

When I change the ID to a real ID, like "`t.Id.Equals(2342)`", the error is resolved; but I do not want to use the real ID.

Comment: Which line causes the error? Is it a compile time error or a run-time error? Can you update the question with a stack trace if there is one?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code instead of
DAL.AspNetUser q = db.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Id == userid.id.ToString());
into
DAL.AspNetUser q = db.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Id == userid.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this `userid` not `null` and `userid.id.ToString()` is not return `null`

```
DAL.AspNetUser q = db.AspNetUsers.Single(t=>t.Id.Equals(userid.id.ToString()));
```

when any lambda variable return `null` then this type of error happen.

To prevent this you can do like this

```
DAL.AspNetUser q = db.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Id == userid.id.ToString());
```

Comment: @soft_94 did you try debugging and see what is the value of `userid.id` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is in the following line which probably does not find the user:

```
DAL.AspNetUser q = db.AspNetUsers.Single(t=>t.Id.Equals(userid.id.ToString()));
```

write it like (depending on the type of id) which will return null when the user is not found:

```
DAL.AspNetUser q = db.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Id == userid.id.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If `t.Id.Equals(2342)` works, then t.Id must not be a string and so you shouldn't be using `.ToString()`

Try

```
db.AspNetUsers.Single(t=>t.Id.Equals(userid.id));
```

or

```
db.AspNetUsers.Single(t=>t.Id == userid.id);
```

Comment: no the id is string and the number just was an example! :) thanks to your response

Comment: In that case, did you try assigning userid.id to a temporary variable and using that variable in your expression?